# MongoDB MapReduce scope of higher order functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, scope, mapreduce

I want to define a helper function for my mapreduce code which can be parametrized with another function (i.e. dependency injection), similar to the definition below:

```
var helper = function(f) {
  return function(x) {
    return f(x); // just an example
  };
}
```

When calling Mongo's mapreduce, I pass the (already resolved) function in the scope:

```
var options = {
  scope: {
    doStuff: helper(someFun)
  },
  …
};

var map = function() { … };
var reduce = function(key, values) { doStuff(…); … };

db.collection('test').mapReduce(map, reduce, options);
```

I would expect that `f` will contain `someFun` in the returned function and can be used in map or reduce functions. But it does not, mapreduce fails and Mongo reports:

> `{ MongoError: ReferenceError: f is not defined : …`

Can this be done? Do I need to rewrite my function so the scope/closure is preserved? If possible, I'd like to avoid defining `f` in the scope too, since I feel that this will likely break in the future (developers forget to add all required functions to the scope, etc.)

Comment: isn't that what `this` keyword in Javascript is for?

Comment: I'm very happy to solve my problem by using `this` in the correct way, although I think that's unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
// re-useable helpers to generate mongodb map functions
// (mongoshell-compatible dependency injection)

// creates a renderDate() function to be used from map() functions
function renderDate() {
  var DAY_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var renderDate = t =>
    new Date(DAY_MS * Math.floor(t / DAY_MS)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
}

// generates a map function after injecting code from the mapHelpers() function
function makeMapWith(mapHelpers, mapTemplate) {
  const getFuncBody = fct => {
    var entire = fct.toString();
    return entire.substring(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));
  };
  return new Function([
    getFuncBody(mapHelpers),
    getFuncBody(mapTemplate),
  ].join('\n'));
}

const map = makeMapWith(renderDate, function mapTemplate(){
  // the body of this map() function can use renderDate
  // because it's injected by makeMapWith() 
  emit(renderDate(this._id.getTimestamp()), {});
});

// the map function can safely be passed to mongodb's mapReduce()
```